# How to create a package using NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I have completed my project using PHP(called myGapApp). Now I have to create a Installer package (one click installation) using NSIS. 
       The installation package should contain Apache server, mysql and myGapApp. By clicking this package all the softwares (Apache server, mysql and myGapApp) should get install in the users computer.

```
  My system configuration is Win XP. Using NSIS.
```

Looking for your solution.

Comment: Do you have any specific problem, or do you want us to write it for you (which we won't do)?

Comment: Thanku, Dear @Cat Plus Plus. I am asking whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to create a installer package using NSIS.
Here is a link which gives example of doing it.
http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~drum/java/lectures/appendix/installer/install.html